# Process ends after input selection

Tags: python

So I'm a newbie programmer trying to learn python and am trying to build a guessing game. So I tried a user input choice of 1,2,3 (difficulty) but when I run it, once after you input its difficulty, it automatically ends the process.

```
def puzzle():
    print("There are 3 puzzles:\n 1. Easy\n 2. Normal\n 3. Hard")
    print("\nWhich will you pick?")
    player_selections = input("Enter a number:")
    if player_selections == 1:
        print("I'm tall when I'm young, and I'm short when I'm old. What am I?")
        answer1 = "Candle", "candle"
        guess1 = ""
        guess_limit1 = 5
        guess_count1 = 0
        out_of_guesses1 = False
        while answer1 != guess1 and not out_of_guesses1:
            if guess_count1 < guess_limit1:
                guess1 = input("What is your guess?:")
                guess_count1 += 1
                print("Wrong! Try again")
            else:
                out_of_guesses1 = True
        if out_of_guesses1:
            print("Out of Guesses, You Lose!")
        else:
            print("You guessed the word. You win!")

    elif player_selections == 2:
        print("I'm tall when I'm young, and I'm short when I'm old. What am I?")
        answer2 = "Candle", "candle"
        guess2 = ""
        guess_limit2 = 5
        guess_count2 = 0
        out_of_guesses2 = False
        while answer2 != guess2 and not out_of_guesses2:
            if guess_count2 < guess_limit2:
                guess2 = input("What is your guess?:")
                guess_count2 += 1
                print("Wrong! Try again")
            else:
                out_of_guesses2 = True
        if out_of_guesses2:
            print("Out of Guesses, You Lose!")
        else:
            print("You guessed the word. You win!")

puzzle()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake I see is:

```
if player_selections == 1:
```

But it should be this:

```
if player_selections == '1':
```

And:

```
elif player_selections == '2':
```

That is because the input data is stored in a string. And the process ends, because there are no True expressions in if-statements.

Hope it helps! If you are satisfied with my answer, I would appreciate you accepting it(there is a tick on the left side)